# Ошибки в <xctk:IntegerUpDown FormatString="N0"> </xctk:IntegerUpDown>

Tags: wpf, .net, xaml

Здравствуйте! Подскажите в чем здесь ошибки.

```
<TextBox Name="ittem_x1" 
             Background="PaleGreen" 
             Grid.Row="0" 
             Margin="65,7,72,0" 
             Height="25"  
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <xctk:IntegerUpDown FormatString="N0">
        </xctk:IntegerUpDown>
    </TextBox>
```

1) Имя "IntegerUpDown" не существует в пространстве имен "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit".   graphics editor C:\Users\gd\Desktop.NET (C#)\graphics editor\graphics editor\Window_draw_line.xaml 25
2) Не удалось найти тип "xctk:IntegerUpDown". Убедитесь, что не пропущена ссылка на сборку и что все сборки, на которые заданы ссылки, выполнены.   graphics editor C:\Users\gd\Desktop.NET (C#)\graphics editor\graphics editor\Window_draw_line.xaml
3) недопустимый код XML "Префикс "xctk" необъявленный., строка 26, позиция 14.".    graphics editor C:\Users\gd\Desktop.NET (C#)\graphics editor\graphics editor\Window_draw_line.xaml

Ссылка на сборку

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструкция, которую вы написали, в принципе не может работать. Вкладывая элемент `IntegerUpDown` в `TextBox` вы тем самым пытаетесь установить его свойство `Text`, которое имеет тип `string`.

```
<TextBox Name="ittem_x1" 
         Background="PaleGreen" 
         Grid.Row="0" 
         Margin="65,7,72,0" 
         Height="25"  
         VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown FormatString="N0"></xctk:IntegerUpDown>
</TextBox>
```

Для того что бы использовать `IntegerUpDown` достаточно установить пакет `Extended.Wpf.Toolkit`

```
PM> Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit
```

и подключить пространство имен:

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

Ниже показан минимальный код, который необходим:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:IntegerUpDown Height="30" FormatString="N0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы в textbox можно было бы вводить только целые неотрицательные числа?

Comment: @user222335 а зачем вам `TextBox` если это все можно сделать силами `IntegerUpDown`?

Comment: Так интересней, когда пользователь сам вводит данные

Comment: @user222335, чтобы вводить целые неотрицательные числа установите свойство `Minimum` элемента `IntegerUpDown` в значение 0

Comment: @user222335 если хотите использовать`TextBox` можно написать `Behaviour`, в котором разрешить ввод только целых чисел.

Comment: @sp7, спасибо попробую

Comment: @user222335 пишите, если не получится.

Comment: @sp7, хорошо. если не получится напишу